# Is it possible to iterator a ListNode with map() or reduce() function?

Tags: python

I have a data structure like :

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

I want to iterator the ListNode one by one until the next is None

I can use `while`, but is it possible to use map() or reduce() or something else to make the code more beautiful ?

Comment: What?  Your class just statically sets its own `next` to None.  So iterating "until the next is None" won't do anything; it already is None.

Comment: How are `map()` and `reduce()` more beautiful than a `while` loop? If anything, you might want to look into generator expressions, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `reduce` is the right tool for the job. First of all, your `ListNode` is not actually iterable, but you can fix that by implementing the `__iter__` function:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x, succ=None):
        self.val = x
        self.succ = succ

    def __iter__(self):
        cur = self
        while cur is not None:
            yield cur
            cur = cur.succ
```

Here, `__iter__` is a generator function, `yield`ing the next successor until the end of the list is reached. Now, you can just use a regular `for` loop to iterate the linked list:

```
lst = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3, ListNode(4, ListNode(5)))))
for ln in lst:
    print ln.val
```